# Handling imbalanced data in R - Error Message

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am trying to handle an imbalanced data set in R. I passed the csv files for the train and test set and I tried to predict but the prediction runs for only the first 10 instances. The output message is:
 predict code called exit with value 1

I cannot understand why. The data set includes numeric and non numeric data. So, I decided to use C50. The another problem here is that the classification tree has only one node from the 18 attributes of the data set. 
Can anyone help to solve the error message above or propose me another machine learning algorithm to hanlde the data?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: @adiana what do you want exactly? sample of data? info about data? my code?

Comment: " I passed the csv files for the train and test set and I tried to predict but the prediction runs for only the first 10 instances. The output message is: predict code called exit with value 1". This is definitely impossible to replicate on our machine

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you partitioned the data into train and test set, you may need to provide more information if you need more specific suggestions. I can give you some thoughts since I have ran into the problems you had as well.

1. After you partitioned your data, make sure do a `summary()` of train and test set to see the summary of your response variable. You can use `table(dataframe$responseVariable)` to see how many of response variable is A or how many is B. (Assuming you are predicting A or B)
   If you train set is very imbalanced, for example, 90% of A while 10% of B, your model might be over fitting, so if you apply that model on your training set, it might give you only 1 node out of 18 predictors you had or no node (the error you got).
2. To deal with imbalanced data, 1) you can boost your model using the argument in C5.0(...trials=10) (trials can be any number).
   2)Also, you may want to include a cost matrix into your c5.0 model as well. A cost matrix is created to weight your class differently. You can look it up online, there are several documentation on cost matrix.
3. I am not sure why your model only run for first 10 rows of test set without knowing more information on what you did or what kind of data you have. However, one thing I can think of is that, maybe in your test set, there are NAs in the response variable, which you should remove those rows where response variables are NAs (for both train and test set)

Final note:
If you tried cost matrix and boosting in C5.0 but still getting only one node (the boosting will likely give you more important variables), you might need to think that that is "answer" that you want. That means that variable has the most information gain out of all predictors.

Hope all this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Important Note: Your train and validation set should have equal number of columns and also make sure the columns are in same order in both training set and validation set. Your input file can be in either of the two formats .CSV or .ARFF

```
    Install.packages(random forest)
    library(random forest)

 Train = read.csv(file.choose(), sep=",",header = TRUE)
 dim(Train)
 Test = read.csv(file.choose(),sep=",",header= TRUE)
 RF <- random forest(class~., data= Train, ntree= 100)
 RPred <- predict(RF, Test)
```

Hope this Helped.

Comment: I have checked the columns of the two data sets. Unfortunately, my code runs only for the first 10 instances (rows) of the test data set and then stops. I use the above code with C50 not random forest. I will check this in a while

Answer (score 0):

In C50, the train data set must have all the factors that are provided in the test set. For example,
Train set:
[John, Mary, Ruth]

Test set:
[John, Mark, Ruth]

If you try to predict using this test set, it will throw the output message: "predict code called exit with value 1" exactly after predicting for "John" because "Mark" is not present in the train set.

In your case, since you mentioned that it throws the error exactly after the 10th row, I would suggest you to check the 11th row in the test data set. It may have a factor that wasn't available in the training data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 11th instance have one NA value in last predictor (attribute). But there 4 other instances with NA in till the 11th attribute. I have checked the attributes in the both data sets.. They are the same.